# Hiding script error messages in IE status bar

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, web-applications

I want to hide the script error messages to display in status bar in IE, is that any way to do it programmatically?

I am aware that we can enclose the script function with try {} catch {}. But this is the way to handle the exceptions and I sure if handled, it won’t displays as error in status bar.

I am searching is there any other way/in-build functions to avoid error messages on status bar.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16185951/2582496 have a look at the end of the function. It returns false, that should mean that the default handler won't do anything more and theoretically it shouldn't show any errors. Try it and leave a comment if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
function hidestatus()
 {
    window.status = ''
    return true
 } 
if (document.layers)
 {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEOVER | Event.MOUSEOUT)
  document.onmouseover = hidestatus
  document.onmouseout = hidestatus
 }
```

But it's not really a googd idea to try to change browsers default behaviour, users can make the choice to hide status bar but it's not your role