# Can an angular directive bind a global exception handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to create a directive that binds a global exception handler, that, say, logs to console and shows a `<div>` in the ui?

I'd like to use it like this:

```
<div with-global-exception-handler>
 ...
</div>
```

Then whatever happens within that `div` that throws an exception would be covered by a that exception handler?

Comment: Yes. Use this solution in your link function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571650/catching-all-javascript-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: @HankScorpio you mean hook up to `window.onerror`? Anything AngularJS specific?

Comment: Not much angular specific, no. Other than using `$window` instead of `window`.