# Is JavaScript error catching possible without modifying the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

In a JS application, how can you catch all the errors that are generated, handled and unhandled without changing the source code ?
Or without going into the code and modifying each managed error.

I have tried acertain error analysis tools, but these are designed for error handling that involves sending specifically to these

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to do this. There are no general error handling parameters that you can change.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571650/catching-all-javascript-unhandled-exceptions).