# How to indicate that an exception was thrown from inside method in JasmineJS?

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine

In Junit testing I can expect an exception to be thrown in the test like this :

```
@Test(expect=SomeExceptino.class)
public void shouldThrowException(){
//test goes here.

}
```

How can I do this with JS and Jasmine ?

I have Something like:

```
function ActionDispatcher() {

    var actionHandlers = {};

    this.dispatch = function (action) {
        var actionHandler = actionHandlers[action.constructor];

        if (actionHandler == undefined) {
            throw new Error('not handler for action:' + action.constructor);
        } else {
            actionHandler.handle(action);
        }
    };
    }
```

How do I write test that expects dispatch to throw exception?

I am spying on action Hanlders not the tested ActionDipatcher. I think it is ridiculous to spy on the object you are testing.

Comment: Try with try, catch statements inside the function

Comment: Aha a good idea I will try right now

Comment: I think this may helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205688/javascript-exception-handling

Comment: It really worked. Thank you. Please Post an answer and let me vote for it.

Comment: actually not really ! I think I have to make some more checking. I notify you when it is OK :D

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine has a `toThrow` matcher that allows you to test for exceptions. You can use it like so:

```
it("throws", function() {
  var dispatcher = new ActionDispatcher();
  expect(function() {
    dispatcher.dispatch({constructor: 'constructor'});
  }).toThrow(new Error('not handler for action: constructor'));
});
```