# jQuery: global exception handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, web, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205688/javascript-exception-handling)

I have a web application where 100% of the javascript code executes as jQuery event handlers (I guess most jQuery apps are like this).

The question is how can I define a global exception handler. That is, if a function that is called when any exception that happens within any jQuery event handler goes uncaught (whether it is onload, click, a succesfull ajax call, an ajax error, whatever). 
My function would receive the error info (exception, stacktrace, whatever).

**Clarification:** I don't mean globally catching in ajax problems generated by the server or network, but globally catching problems that are due to (presumably) bugs in our code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this can be achieved using concepts from the [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

We can simply create a wrapper of `jQuery.event.dispatch` which will handle the errors:

```
(function () {
    var temp = jQuery.event.handle;
    jQuery.event.handle = function () {
       try {
          temp.apply(this, arguments);
       } catch (e) {
          console.log('Error while dispatching the event.');
       }
    }
}());
$(document).click(function () {
    throw 'Some error...';
});
```

Using this approach you must be very careful because of changes in the internal interface

- Note the example above works for jQuery v1.6.3, in jQuery 1.7.1 `jQuery.event.dispatch` instead of `jQuery.event.handle`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `window.onerror` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror

```
window.onerror = function errorHandler(msg, url, line) {

  console.log(arguments);

  // Just let default handler run.
  return false;
}
```

Comment: this almost never works. :) 
`Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically` they said.

Comment: @mayankcpdixit [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/5mpL7u0p/). Can you cite an example of something that doesn't get caught?

Comment: Modern style [works too](https://jsfiddle.net/5mpL7u0p/1/).

Comment: Well for example: If you are using Angular, errors wont pass through `window.onerror`. You have to handle them using factory.

`window.onerror` is not triggered when the console directly generates an error.

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception won't be caught by this

Comment: Good solution. One remark: there should be a semicolon after closing curly bracket, because this is an assignment statement.