# Jquery get browser console log

Tags: jquery, logging, console

It is possible to get with JQuery the browser console log.

I want to save it like error log to view user actions if have errors.. I try some solutions finded in search engines but does not have effect.

Comment: ah.. sorry didn't understood. can you please separate out sentences and be more clear ?

Comment: When browser loads some page in browser console shows some js error if have.. Its possible to grab this console log?

Comment: a simple try - catch block ? did you try that ? or a global exception handler. this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14374719/1660192, http://stackoverflow.com/q/205688/1660192

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy what is in the console, just select it and press ctrl + c (copy). Is the same process as copy - paste any other text. I hope this is what you want to do.

Comment: No i do not mean only my console i want to save each clieng console