# Error handling error based on error code in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I created a command line app in node.js which heavily relies on file system module of node (read, update, create new file etc). I write many functions for the same purpose.

Now my question is : 'Can I globally catch the error that occurred due to any function?'

For example:

```
func1();  // throws some error: Cannot find file , errCode:xyz
func2();  // throws some error: Cannot find file , errCode:xyz

//some global error catcher    
func(catch errCode:xyz){
          console.log("Cannot find file. Make sure file exist and path is correct.");
    }
```

ss

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205688/javascript-exception-handling

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to  https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function handler(err) {
  // do stuf based on err, but make sure node.js quits after
  // displaying the error and performing basic cleanup - see below
})
```

However this is not recommended, and you certainly should not let your application keep running after this since it might be in an unknown state.

You functions should perform a callback with the error first, node-style, and the function that passed the callback should handle the error in the correct way.